# git-svn dcommit fail for "URL access forbidden for unknown reason"

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

When I type git svn dcommit, I got this

```
Committing to https://some.server.com/proj1/v3 ...
URL access forbidden for unknown reason: access to '/proj1/!svn/bc/579/v3/path/to/a.php' forbidden at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 922
```

I've verified `git svn rebase` works, which suggest that my account is right. Is there any advice or any documentation about how git-svn works?

Comment: Maybe is a permission problem on the file. Have you tried to open that file via a browser?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by moving (deleting) the authentication file located at `~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/<file>` (on Linux).

Then I ran `git svn dcommit` again, entered my password when prompted, and now it's working.